# Chrome and oninput events

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a textbox, and I am trying to fire an event oninput (my example below only removes a comma from the input, however I do need it to do more advance things).  My code works great on Firefox and Internet Explorer, however when I click into the textbox in Chrome, I have about .5 seconds to start typing, otherwise I loose focus.  Testing the exact code below on my website creates the error.  Any idea?

```
<input type="text" id="question" name="question" oninput="clean(this);" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function clean(q){
        q.value=q.value.replace(",","");
    }
</script>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qxHW4/

Comment: Was about to comment the same thing as @ComFreek. Chrome v28

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting.  I wonder if some of my other JS, for whatever reason, is interfering.  Let me play around with this a bit and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to ComFreek and RobH for pointing it out that it works just fine on JS fiddle.  I feel quite dumb for not trying it first.  Turns out that some of the other Javascript on the page was causing the trigger to break.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: When I face a strange problem in JS/DOM, I try to isolate the code causing the problem. If the error disappears then, one can be sure that some other code introduces the problem. +1 btw ;)

Comment: Was working on it, it made me wait 2 days before I could accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a timer to run the code in the function.

```
<input type="text" id="question" name="question" oninput="clean(this);" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function clean(q){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            q.value=q.value.replace(",","");
        }, 0);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do some complex things I'd recommend you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), because will fix this crossbrowser errors.

and use something like:

```
$('#input-desired').bind('keyup', function() {
     this.value = this.value.replace(',', '');
});
```

If you wanna go for a simple application you can try this.

```
<input type="input" id="desired" onkeyup="desiredInputChanges(this);" />
```

In your Javascript file use something like:

```
desiredInputChanges = function (input) {
   input.value = input.value.replace(',', '');
}
```

Just a note, don't forget to make a function to be your class and protect your methods :)

Comment: -1 because you cannot simply suggest jQuery if someone faces a problem with a specific browser. This is ridiculous. jQuery is **not** a panacea. In addition, why do you use `$(this).val()`? You could just use `this.value`. The other way is unnecessary overhead. Rewritten: `this.value = this.value.replace(',', '');`

Comment: I didn't do that, he specified that would like to do some complex things. I'd never recommend jQuery for something like this, but in the beginning of his text he tell that will do more complex things. I completely agree with you.

Comment: I think he wants to do some more advanced string manipulation. Anyway, it would be nice if you edit your answer in order to include a general solution (e.g. *use keyup event*) and in order to simplify the jQuery code ;)

Comment: Sorry guys about my mistakes, I'll give more attention in another answers. I think the answer is ok right now. Cheers.

Comment: No need for execuse here ;) (I'm sorry for my many little edits.). I forgot to say *welcome to StackOverflow*.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to be helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<input onkeyup="clean(this)">`, it will only fire the function after something is typed into the input.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Comment: I have the same issue with onkeyup when I first start typing.  Once I get going, it seems the issue goes away.  Still not ideal.